# How to fix an error in simplest PandasGUI script

Tags: python, pandasgui

I am trying to run the simplest pandasGUI example.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasgui import show
df = pd.DataFrame(([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
show(df)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 12, in <module>
    show(df)    
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\gui.py", line 460, in show
    pandas_gui = PandasGui(settings=settings, **kwargs)    
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\gui.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.init_ui()   
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\gui.py", line 161, in init_ui
    self.store.settings.settingsChanged.connect(self.apply_settings)   
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type SettingsStore has been deleted
```

Has anyone any ideas how to fix this situation?

Comment: The code runs fine for me, but it was difficult to get pandasgui to work. You could try `pip install --upgrade pandasgui` to see if that fixes it. Otherwise I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your idea, but unfortunately to no avail. This is very strange, since my example is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Graphics Backend in Preferences->IPython console->Graphics->Backend to Tkinter worked for me.